# Android best practices for fragment animations

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation

I have activity with two tabs. Both tab uses different fragments. When a particular event occur like user click on item, I am opening another fragment in same activity.

I know how to add fragment dynamically and I also know how to animate it.

Here, how I added fragment to `frameLayout` in my activity:

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.object_slide_in_up, R.animator.activity_hold)
transaction.add(R.id.flSellerHome, fragment)
transaction.commit()
```

Everything works fine in emulator and newer phones. I have tested with emulator with api 25, it works fine now flickering occur, When I am testing it with real device with api 23 it flicker little, so it doesn't affect, after then when I tested it with api 19, it flickers too much.

So my question is any best practise for doing animation.

### Notes

- My third fragment which is dynamically added contains recylerview with around 20 items from local db, and I also done db fatching in background thread.
- No loads on main thread. recyclerview is also simple with one Image and three texts.
- Image is also loaded using Glide and also I have override function of glide**

any help is appreciated..

Comment: without giving reason please do not give minus...

Comment: I would say this question is a little too broad of a question. Perhaps performance of the phone affects the behavior? There are way too many possible variables as to what can cause "flickering". Also moving between API versions could result in differences to how RecyclerView is being processed. Probably should profile your code to help narrow down the problem.

Comment: Many things may cause flickering, inflating a big scaled image, badly constructed complex layout, doing so much process on main thread when inflating fragments layout etc.

Comment: U have done the right way of animation but put the small duration around 150 other wise it will cause the performance and u may get ANR report also.

Comment: More information is needed, but if i were to guess i wold say your layout may be too complex. when adding a fragment you also get a request layout for the entire activity so if the layout on top of witch you put the new fragment is complex that will add to the problem. You should profile your code to see more in depth where the problem lies.

Comment: did you play with the visibility of the fragment like adding all the fragments all together and changing the visibility as per your need?

Comment: @ReyanshMishra I have tabbed activity with two fragments,, and one full screen fragment added dynamically after user clicks.. so no need to play with visibility

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found problem is with recyclerview data updation.

I am loading data in background thread, but when notifying recyclerview, it stucks for small amout of time.

So what I have done is. I have delayed data load for same amount of time which is for animation.

I don't know it is good idea or bad idea. But it is too late for my project so I used this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to write comment to your answer, but I dont have enough rep, but I want try to advice you something, so sorry for this.

> I am loading data in background thread, but when notifying recyclerview, it stucks for small amout of time.

Try to start loading, which you did, after click and show simple ProgressBar, and when data is loaded, hide progress bar, set info to your fragment and then show fragment. Then you will have all data wich you need in fragment when it is attached and can put it (data) to your adapter.

It have to look good.

Comment: Without understanding question. Please do not give answer

Comment: @LalitJadav it wasnt answer, it was small advice. You can to listen to it or not.

Comment: @LalitJadav I am not asking you something. Relax

Answer (score -3):

If it occurs only for API 19 and lower, it may be a lack of performance from the device.

Maybe the problem do not come from Fragments and Animations, but from another functionality which slow down the UI thread. By functionality, I mean the way your fragments communicate together. Do they share a huge amount of data ? Or heavyweight datas ? If so, you should use Async Tasks or Threads.

Good luck !

Comment: I have already said everything in my question.. no any other functionality slow downs performance. Btw thanks for help